# How do I check if 3 or more values are the same in my Firebase database?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to return all of the users in my table view that have 3 attributes that are equal to "art", "music" & "sports". The other users that have 3 attributes that are not equal to these 3 strings will not show in my table view. How do I achieve this? At the moment, I can only check if **ONE** attribute is equal to **ONE** string like in my example below. I have an image of my database tree below, along with the code that I currently have. Any appreciate any help. Thank you!

[image]

```
class User: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var numberId: String?

    var attribute1: String?
    var attribute2: String?
    var attribute3: String?

    var password: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
}

func fetchUser() {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "attribute1").queryEqual(toValue: "art").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()

                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                self.users.append(user)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        cell .detailTextLabel?.text = user.email

        if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {

            cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (major, in my opinion) limitation of Firebase is its inability to filter by multiple keys at once. The general strategy for doing this is to filter by the key that you think will give you the smallest data set to work with, and filter by the remaining keys on the client side. So, for instance, if you think your current filter will give you the smallest set (or if they'll all give about the same), before you append the user, check:

```
if user.attribute2 == "music" && user.attribute3 == "sports" {
    self.users.append(user)
}
```

You could also filter your list once you have all of your users. But the point is Firebase doesn't currently allow for this sort of filtering, so you'll need to do it client side.

```
self.users = self.users.filter({ $0.attribute2 == "music" && $0.attribute3 == "sports" })
```